# std::regex_match with another Allocator

Tags: regex, c++11, stl, allocator

I'm stuck how to use the `regex_match` template with my own Memory STL  Allocator.

This is my code:

```
FaF::smatch stringResults;
std::regex expression( "expression" );
std::regex_match( FaF::string-variable, stringResults, expression );
```

For `std::match` and `std::string` I was successful and therefore I use it in the above example:

```
namespace FaF
{
    using smatch = std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator,
                                          Allocator<std::string::const_iterator>>;
    using string = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Allocator<char>>;
}
```

My Allocator has some logging and I can see clearly, yes it is indeed used.
When I understand the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) correctly, then `std::regex` does not have an allocator, but `std::regex_match` [does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match).

**My question:**

How to define - according the above types - in the `namespace FaF` an additional template based on `std::regex_match` which is using my STL Memory Allocator?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what problem you think you have. `std::regex_match` automatically picks up allocators from its first and second arguments, via the magic known as "template argument deduction". Is this not what you want? What additional definition you feel you need, and why?

Comment: By the way, `std::match_results<Iter, Alloc>` uses its allocator to allocate instances of `std::sub_match<Iter>`, not just `Iter` as your typedef suggests you believe.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik 1) I already suspected that I have to extend the `Iter` item as well. 2) I don't think `std::regex_match` does use the same allocator because my log shows me it was called 5 times and `stringResults` has 5 items. I changed it also to 4 and the log displayed 4 allocation. Therefore I asked this question because for me it is clear there is no "template argument deduction".

Comment: I'm confused. You say the allocator is called the same number of times as there were results. To me, that sounds like proof positive that the allocator is working as intended. What again seems to be the problem?

Comment: `std::regex` does have an allocator associated with it, somewhat indirectly. `std::basic_regex` has a `Traits` parameter, which among other things provides `string_type` typedef, which is some instantiation of `std::basic_string`, and that has an allocator baked into it. Perhaps that's what you are looking for. In this case, you'd need to define your own traits structure that defines `string_type` as a string using your allocator.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Check my answer. If you think it is what you said in your first comment then reply and I will credit my answer to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After *studying* the definition of `std::regex_match` in `regex.h`

```
  template<typename _Ch_traits, typename _Ch_alloc,
       typename _Alloc, typename _Ch_type, typename _Rx_traits>
    inline bool
    regex_match(const basic_string<_Ch_type, _Ch_traits, _Ch_alloc>& __s,
        match_results<typename basic_string<_Ch_type,
        _Ch_traits, _Ch_alloc>::const_iterator, _Alloc>& __m,
        const basic_regex<_Ch_type, _Rx_traits>& __re,
        regex_constants::match_flag_type __flags
        = regex_constants::match_default)
    { return regex_match(__s.begin(), __s.end(), __m, __re, __flags); }
```

I understood and realized that my own definition of `FaF::string` and defining my own `FaF::smatch` [definitions are in the question] is enough because the `_Alloc` is used there.

My code is like this:

```
void getBarDataEntryFromMySql( const FaF::string & memcacheBarDataEntry )
{
    const char expressionString [] = "expression";

    FaF::smatch stringResults;
    std::regex expression( expressionString );
    std::regex_match( memcacheBarDataEntry, stringResults, expression );

    ...
}
```

and it works. I was thinking too complicated...

Answer (score 0):

According to *cppreference.com*, the second argument of `regex_match` should be

```
std::match_results<typename std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc>::const_iterator, Alloc>
```

where the first argument would be a `std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc>`.

This would require your alias declarations in `FaF` to like somewhat like:

```
namespace FaF
{
    using string_type = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
                            Allocator<char>>;
    using match_type  = std::match_results<string_type::const_iterator, 
                            Allocator<string_type::const_iterator>>;
}
```

in order to have

- results and
- string characters allocated via your allocator and
- correct arguments.

Comment: `std::regex_match` doesn't allocate any "string characters"; `SAlloc` isn't used for anything. `std::regex_match(string, ...)` simply turns around and calls `std::regex_match(string.begin(), string.end(), ...)`. The latter doesn't have `SAlloc` anymore, but only one allocator, used to allocate `std::sub_match` instances.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: `SAlloc` is used to allocate the characters of the string. passed into the overload in question. OP obviously wants the custom allocator for both `string` and iterator.

Comment: `std::regex_match` doesn't allocate any characters of any string though. Its `basic_string` parameter is `const`. Its output is a list of `std::sub_match` objects, each holding a pair of iterators into the original string.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I didn't claim that a call to `regex_match` allocates characters. The alias declaration of `string_type` with `Allocator<char>` has the consequence that the passed string has its characters allocated via `Allocator` and the declaration of| `match_type` has the consequence that the result iterators are allocated via `Allocator`.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, VS 2017 fails to compile the match_type, because it needs to use sub_match:

```
using match_type = std::match_results<string_type::const_iterator,
    Allocator<std::sub_match<string_type::const_iterator>>>;
```

EDIT: It doesn't actually seem possible to fully override the allocator used by std::regex in VS2017. There are some std::vector's that don't take the allocator param, used internally by the _Matcher object. This is annoying :(