# Use custom allocator for std::regex_match

Tags: c++, stl

I want to route all allocations performed by std::regex_match through a custom allocator.

Based on [std::regex_match with another Allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124358/stdregex-match-with-another-allocator) I was able to re-route some of them, by doing:

```
using string_type = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Allocator<char>>;
using match_type = std::match_results<string_type::const_iterator, Allocator<std::sub_match<string_type::const_iterator>>>;

string_type value;
match_type::allocator_type allocator;
match_type results(allocator);
std::regex expression("expression");
std::regex_match(value, results, expression);
```

But there are some `std::vectors`, internal to the `_Matcher` class, which don't use the passed allocators. Is this an oversight in VS2017's STL library, or am i doing something wrong? Is there anythign I can do to work around this?

The vectors that don't use the allocator, in `<regex>` are:

```
_Tgt_state_t<_It> _Tgt_state; // contains vector<_Grp_t> _Grps;
_Tgt_state_t<_It> _Res; // contains vector<_Grp_t> _Grps;
vector<_Loop_vals_t> _Loop_vals;
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've filed this as https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/174 . As far as I can tell, the Standard is silent on this topic, so both MSVC's and libc++'s behaviors are conformant. It seems reasonable to use the match_results allocator, but really the Standardese should be overhauled to require a particular behavior.

Comment: Thank you for reporting the issue to Microsoft!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it is an oversight in VS2017's STL library; I looked at libc++, and it seems to use the allocator internally for the vector.